# How to have a proper between query that uses hashed/indexed structure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I couldn't find a solution for this question as it seems extremely complicated one

Here i have 1 table with 3 columns

```
CodeVal_1   bigint  Unchecked 
CodeVal_2   bigint  Unchecked
CountryCode char(2) Unchecked
```

CodeVal_1 and CodeVal_2 together composes primary key

So this table holds data like below

```
CodeVal_1   CodeVal_2   CountryCode
7602176     7864319     AT
16777216    16777471    AU
16777472    16778239    CN
16778240    16779263    AU
16779264    16781311    CN
16781312    16785407    JP
16785408    16793599    CN
```

Now i need to query this table as

```
select CountryCode from tblCountryCodes where 215454 between CodeVal_1 and CodeVal_2
```

This perfectly works at SQL server however it is slow to make each query call. So i want to make this work at whole C# code with some preloading etc.

However i could not find a proper way which would work faster than SQL server 2014

Is that possible to achieve it with some kind of double indexing (i have no idea about this just throwing idea), hash tables, dictionary etc

Waiting your ideas and suggestions

Comment: It looks like `CodeVal_2` is always greater than `CodeVal_1`? If `CodeVal_2` is sorted, you could do an abbreviated search. You could get away with just checking records while `CodeVal_2` is greater than or equal to the number you're checking it against. Or even split the records up into multiple lists (maybe number_of_lists = number_of_records divided by 100 or 1000 or something), find the list that the search number would fall into, and do the aforementioned abbreviated search on just that list.

Comment: itsme86 can you elaborate how to check greater than or etc at csharp with a fast way ? are there such index structure or etc instead of each time scanning entire memory ?

Comment: how many rows does your table have? Would they all fit into memory?

Answer (score 0):

By "make each query call" do you mean you are making multiple calls subbing in different values for 215454?

If this is the case you can provide multiple values to your stored procedure via comma separated string (split by a function), xml or table-valued parameter to allow you to retrieve multiple in a single call.  For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Table_SetVisibility] (
    @TableIds VARCHAR(MAX),
    @IsVisible BIT
)
AS

    UPDATE  e
    SET     e.IsVisible = @IsVisible
    FROM    dbo.udf_SplitString(@TableIds, ',') s
        INNER JOIN dbo.[Table] e ON e.TableId = s.Value;

GO
```

Comment: ty for answer however each time single query with different value. i am really looking for non SQL server solution as it is maximal optimized atm